# system call not parsing output to a file in c, file created but no data inside the file

Tags: c

I have  written a small code which takes input from the user and passes it to the system ("command>/tmp/j"), here the file j is being created but there is no information inside it related to the input present in the command.
For eg: If I have given ps -f as input to the string command, the system() should execute it and store it inside file /tmp/j, but here the **file j** is being created but there is no output data inside it.

I have seen many questions, but all those are using popen() and the input is predefined in them.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
main()
{
  enum msgtype {PROCESS_LIST_REQUEST=1, PROCESS_LIST_RESPONSE, DIRECTORY_LIST_REQUEST, DIRECTORY_LIST_RESPONSE, ERROR_REQUEST};
  struct head 
  {
      int version;
      int   msg_length;
      int   header_length;
      enum msgtype msg_type;
      char data;
      char *reqtype;
  };

  struct head *buf;
  buf = malloc((sizeof(struct head)));
  buf->reqtype=malloc(40);
  char req[10];
  char *command;
  command = malloc((sizeof(char) * 10));
  fgets(req, sizeof(req),stdin);
  buf->reqtype = req;
  printf("%s" , buf->reqtype); //just to make sure correct thing is present
  command = buf->reqtype;
  printf("%s",command);//just to make sure correct thing is present
  system ("command>/tmp/j");
  {
      FILE *fp;
      char c;
      fp = fopen("/tmp/j", "r");
      if (fp == NULL)
           printf("File doesn't exist\n"); 
      else {
       do {
            c = getc(fp); 
            putchar(c); 
    } while (c != EOF); 
   }
  fclose(fp);
}
}
```

Comment: When you run your executable file then you have to write with `>` . Something like this - `a.exe>file.txt` . I would suggest you to use `fopen` and `fprintf` .

Comment: the declaration of main() has two valid formats (and one optional format) .  All valid main() declarations have the return type set to 'int'

Comment: for readability/understandability by us humans, please indent the code consistently,  Do not use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab widths set differently,  Suggest indenting by 4 spaces as that does not eat up the page width and is visible even with variable width fonts.  Suggest indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: when calling malloc() and family of functions, always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the posted code does not compile,  It is missing `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: in the parameter for malloc() the expression: `sizeof(char)`, which is defined by the standard to always be 1, has absolutely no effect, just clutters the code, and should be removed

Comment: @user3629249 Then its better to not use pointers . Just use arrays  :-)

Comment: when calling `fgets()` the returned value should always be checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the posted code is trying to get input from the user, without first prompting the user for the correct input.   This leaves the user with a blank screen with a blinking cursor and no indication of what the user should do next

Comment: the function: `fgets()` also inputs the trailing newline.  For the posted code, that is a problem.  Suggest adding a statement (or two) to replace any newline with a NUL byte

Comment: this line: `system ("command>/tmp/j");`  does not do what your expecting.   Suggest using a buffer and sprintf() to generate the complete string, then `system( buffer );`

Comment: when calling `fopen()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code malloc's three memory allocations.  to avoid a memory leak, pass each of those allocation pointers to `free()`

Comment: @ameyCU,  your conclusion to always use arrays rather than pointers to allocated memory is based on what?   That assertion is certainly NOT what I said

Comment: @user3629249 No **not always** , it is not . But if he has to do `p=malloc(25)` , then better to use array .

Comment: in general, the definitions (not the declarations of instances) of the struct and enum should be outside of any function.

Comment: regarding this line: `command = malloc(10);`  since command is a char *, this results in a pointer to 10 bytes of allocated memory.  However, this line: `command = buf->reqtype;` overlays that pointer with a new pointer.  The result is the pointer to the original malloc'd 10 bytes is lost and can never be recovered,  The result is a memory leak.   Suggest removing the line: `command = malloc(10);`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
  system ("command>/tmp/j");
```

Tries to run an executable literally called `command`, and redirects its output to `/tmp/j`.  The redirection happens, thus creating the file `/tmp/j`, but then `command` (whatever it may be) produces no output.

Also, this

```
  command = malloc((sizeof(char) * 10));
```

followed by this

```
  command = buf->reqtype;
```

causes the memory from the `malloc()` call to leak.

Comment: Maybe you should tell OP how to fix these problems.

Comment: @ameyCU - The OP will actually learn something by doing that himself.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So how should I modify the   `system("command>/tmp/j");` to produce desired output and thanks for memory leak, I modified it.

Answer (score 0):

As somebody else says

```
 system ("command>/tmp/j");
```

tries to run a program called 'command'. YOu need to do

```
char buff[256];
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s>/tmp/j", command);
system(buff);
```

Comment: the problem with your suggestion is the output is getting printed and text file is being created, but the j.txt file is empty it doesn't contain anything that is thrown on the screen. So, when i print the buff its just taking  '%s' only nothing after that.